# Optimize SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, optimization

I'm running this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(ALFA_CLAVE, FECHA_NACI) FROM listado GROUP BY ALFA_CLAVE HAVING count(CONCAT(ALFA_CLAVE, FECHA_NACI)) > 1
```

Is there any way to optimize it? Queries are taking 2-3 hours on a table with 850,000 rows.

Adding an index to ALFA_CLAVE and FECHA_NACI would work?

Answer (score 1):

mysql don't have [functional](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/indexes-functional.html)/[expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/indexes-expressional.html) index capability, it cannot put an index on a function/expression.

try it this way, i.e. concat them later:

```
select concat(x.alfa_clave, x.fecha_naci) 
from
(
    SELECT ALFA_CLAVE, FECHA_NACI 
    FROM listado 
    GROUP ALFA_CLAVE, FECHA_NACI 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) as x
```

Comment: If you put the sub-select in a temporary table first, you can shave off some seconds:

create temporary table `temp1`
    SELECT ALFA_CLAVE, FECHA_NACI 
    FROM listado 
    GROUP ALFA_CLAVE, FECHA_NACI 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

select concat(alfa_clave, fecha_naci) from temp1;